# Can't push / pull few of my own github repo with ssh on Win10

Tags: git, github

I am failing to push and pull from some of my repos (not all, just some).
The solutions that I found so far didn't work.
I tried to `git init`, to restart my computer and to set `git config http.sslVerify "false"` but none worked.
It follows the output of `ssh -vT git@github.com`

```
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Barzi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out
```

In my understanding, the line containing `id_ed25519` does not end with `-1`, thus suggesting me that the authentication happened.
So, I don't really don't know what to try next.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Switched to `https://` solved the problem.
As explained [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port), some firewall may refuse `ssh` connections.
Hence, you could try to go SSH over HTTPS.
To check if it is possible, run the following:

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

If you don't get any welcome message, it means that you could not go SSH over HTTPS and therefore you must switch to HTTPS by running the following:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories).